# F# Http.AsyncRequestStream just 'hangs' on long queries

Tags: http, f#, f#-data

I am working with:

```
let callTheAPI = async {
    printfn "\t\t\tMAKING REQUEST at %s..." (System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"))
    let! response = Http.AsyncRequestStream(url,query,headers,httpMethod,requestBody)
    printfn "\t\t\t\tREQUEST MADE."
}
```

And

```
let cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()
let timeout = 1000*60*4//4 minutes (4 mins no grace)
cts.CancelAfter(timeout)
Async.RunSynchronously(callTheAPI,timeout,cts.Token) 
use respStrm = response.ResponseStream
respStrm.Flush()
writeLinesTo output (responseLines respStrm)
```

To call a web API (REST) and the `let! response = Http.AsyncRequestStream(url,query,headers,httpMethod,requestBody)` just hangs on certain queries. Ones that take a long time (>4 minutes) particularly. This is why I have made it Async and put a 4 minute timeout. (I collect the calls that timeout and make them with smaller time range parameters).

I started `Http.RequestStream` from FSharp.Data first, but I couldn't add a timeout to this so the script would just 'hang'.

I have looked at the API's IIS server and the `application pool` `Worker Process` `active requests` in IIS manager and I can see the requests come in and go again. They then 'vanish' and the F# script hangs. I can't find an error message anywhere on the script side or server side.

I included the `Flush()` and removed the timeout and it still hung. (Removing the Async in the process)

Additional: 
Successful calls are made. Failed calls can be followed by successful calls. However, it seems to get to a point where all the calls time out and the do so without even reaching the server any more. (Worker Process Active Requests doesn't show the query)

Update: 
I made the Fsx script output the queries and ran them through IRM with now issues (I have timeout and it never locks up). I have a suspicion that there is an issue with FSharp.Data.Http.

Comment: Are you calling from inside a UI or web request? Could it be this issue ( http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html ) causing a deadlock?

Comment: I am calling from in an .fsx script run from interactive in VS2015. I have run the without any explicit Async at all. Using just ```Http.RequestStream``` from FSharp.Data (without a timeout) and I see the same behaviour. (Except, no timeout, and the first query to 'hang' just hangs.). Simply ```let response = Http.RequestStream(url,query,headers,httpMethod,requestBody)``` and ```use respStm = response.ResponseStream;; respStm.Flush();; writeLinesTo output (responseLines respStm)```. I only used an Async block for the timeout.

Comment: Additional: I can't relate to the article, besides one small thing. I am changing the call in my async block from ```let!``` to   `let response = Http.RequestStream(url,query,headers,httpMethod,requestBody)``` to see if that helps.

Comment: Additional: removing the let! appears to stop the timeout from working. So the call just hangs ...

Answer (score 0):

`Async.RunSynchronously` blocks. Read the remarks section in the docs: [RunSynchronously](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370262.aspx).  Instead, use `Async.AwaitTask`.

Comment: It's a real shame all the async articles use RunSynchronously in the demo code and never explain this.

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks. AwaitTask doesn't take a CancellationToken or take a timeout parameter. The only reason I am using RunSynchronously is so I can time out the task.

Comment: I am trying: ```let task = Async.StartAsTask(callTheAPI,cancellationToken = cts.Token)
                task.Wait()``` to see if I can still get the timeout behaviour

Comment: This failed in the same way. I am now investigating a non-fsharp method of making the call. To find out if it is the FSharp.Data library or not.